# How to export thunderbird profile (Ubuntu to Manjaro)?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, manjaro, thunderbird

I want to export my thunderbird profile from my Ubuntu machine to my new laptop running Manjaro.

I thought that copying my profile folder would suffice so on my Manjaro machine I executed:

```
scp -r philipp@ubuntu-laptop:/home/philipp/.thunderbird /home/philipp/.thunderbird
```

Yet when I start thunderbird on my new machine, it greets with a Welcome screen and a default account setup. I don't want to do that.

How can I export / import my thunderbird profile?

Am I using the correct path for the profile? Does thunderbird on Manjaro maybe use a different configuration folder? If so, how would I know?

Comment: You often have to start Thunderbird so it creates a default profile. Then edit profile.ini & profile_shared.ini from new profile back to your profile. I then delete the "new"  empty profile once I know it is working.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -r philipp@ubuntu-laptop:/home/philipp/.thunderbird /home/philipp
```

would have worked. Not to copy it twice run this on your destination device:

```
cd ~/.thunderbird/.thunderbird && mv * .. && cd .. && rmdir .thunderbird
```

What you actually did was copying the `.thunderbird` directory from your source device to the `.thunderbird` directory at the destination, so now instead of having `~/.thunderbird` you have `~/.thunderbird/.thunderbird`.

Answer (score 0):

Start via `thunderbird -p`, create a new profile and then us "Choose folder" and select the directory you copied  (the one that is named like `abcde123.default`)

[image: GUI explanation]

Answer (score 0):

One can look up thunderbird's profile path via:

`Help > More Troubleshoot Information`

There is a button on `Profile path` from which one can see the target. (For some reason it won't print the path.) While I can validate that my profile path was correct on my Ubuntu machine, nothing would open on my manjaro machine.

That made me doublecheck how I installed my Thunderbird: it turned out on Manjaro I was using the flatpak instance. I removed it via flatpack, installed it from the package manager. That one would use the correct path.

Thunderbird would still on the first start run a wizard to craete a new profile. I closed thunderbird, and replaced the content of the `/home/philipp/.thunderbird/profiles.ini` with the one of my Ubuntu machine. On a new start, my profile was discovred and used.